# generate rss according to views argument in drupal

Tags: drupal, rss, view

is it possible to generate RSS according to views(module) argument?

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course, you can generate RSS in a view by adding a Display of type 'Feed" (a Display just like `Page` and `Block` except that it generates RSS xml. This is a normal feed with a URL of its own and you **can pass it any arguments**.

e.g. if your feed is at `my_view/feed` you can pass it an argument `my_view/feed/<argument>`

Here is a useful tutorial http://www.brighthub.com/office/home/reviews/10563.aspx

Comment: @Victor: did the answer help you?